Issue with LAN7801 USB-to-Ethernet Adapter on RSB3720 with KSZ9897 Using Kernel 5.15
I am currently working with the KSZ9897 Ethernet switch connected to an RSB3720 board. The Ethernet ports have been configured correctly, but I am encountering an issue with the LAN7801 USB-to-Ethernet adapter when attempting to initialize the PHY.
Details: Board: RSB3720 Switch: KSZ9897 Adapter: LAN7801 (USB-to-Ethernet) Kernel Version: 5.15 Issue: The LAN7801 is unable to detect the PHY driver, as indicated by the kernel logs. Kernel Logs:

[ 2586.345280] TRACE 1 of_mdiobus_register done
[ 2586.349570] TRACE 1 dev->mdiobus->id -964161520
[ 2586.354204] lan78xx: Remote wakeup capability is enabled
[ 2586.359523] [DEBUG1] the mdiio value is 0000000053e716ae
[ 2586.359529] [DEBUG2] the mdiio value is lan78xx-mdio
[ 2586.364844] [DEBUG3] the mdiio value is 2
[ 2586.370070] TRACE 1 phydev -972208128
[ 2586.377747] TRACE 1 phydev phy_id 0
[ 2586.381239] TRACE 1 phydev drv 0
[ 2586.384470] lan78xx 3-1.2:1.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): no PHY driver found
[ 2586.392483] lan78xx 3-1.2:1.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): lan7801: PHY Init Failed
[ 2586.401482] lan78xx: probe of 3-1.2:1.0 failed with error -5


I have added debugging information to trace the issue, and it appears that the phydev pointer is not being initialized properly, resulting in the PHY driver not being detected.
Request: Could you please provide guidance or any known solutions for this issue? Specifically, I am seeking advice on:
Proper configuration for the LAN7801 PHY driver. Any additional kernel configurations or patches that might be required. Known compatibility or issues with KSZ9897 on kernel version 5.15.
